# Jekyll can't compile .sass files

Tags: sass, jekyll

Jekyll simply won't compile any of my .sass files when I run it with
`bundle exec jekyll build`,
but `jekyll serve -l` works just fine. It's really irritating, because my sass works in a development environment, but breaks if I upload it to Github pages.

The error:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/styles.scss':
                  Invalid CSS after " 50px": expected "}", was ";" on line 3
jekyll 3.9.0 | Error:  Invalid CSS after " 50px": expected "}", was ";" on line 3
```

assets/css/styles.scss:

```
---
---

@import "base";
```

_sass/base.sass:

```
\:root
    --navheight: 50px;
    --backgroundcolor: #1b111d
    --textcolor: #F4F3EF
    --navlink: #2478ed
```

I'm pretty sure base.sass on line 3 is where it's breaking, not styles.scss. Not sure why the error displays itself that way.

Comment: For anyone coming here because of this error after the upgrade to the Dart SASS compiler. I figured out that it does not like the word "style" in the filename. For example if you have `@import "main_style";` rename your file to something like "main.scss" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so turns out I just had to remove all the semicolons. That was pretty easy, I guess.